# How can use material UI Pickers KeyboardDatePicker with DD/MMM/YYYY format or with a custom input field

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

Currently my datepicker looks like this

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  KeyboardDatePicker,
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider
} from "@material-ui/pickers";
import MomentUtils from "@date-io/moment";
function KeyboardDatePickerExample(props) {
  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(new Date());

  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
      <KeyboardDatePicker
        value={selectedDate}
        onChange={(date) => handleDateChange(date)}
        format="DD/MMM/YYYY"
      />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
}

export default KeyboardDatePickerExample;
```

However, when I try to type the date, it is only numbers so it looks like 00/000/0000 instead of 00/Dec/0000.

So I was wondering if there is a way to fix this, or use my own input field.

https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-goodall-7bn71

Comment: can you provide a code sandbox code? I have created this [CodesandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-67t0bt) but it is crashing as soon as I am opening the picker, let me know what I am missing

Comment: Hi I have edited the post and shared a codesandbox link. The crashing went away once i used the latest moment 1.x version.

Answer (score 0):

You also should notice that:

> Important: For material-ui-pickers v3 use v1.x version of @date-io adapters.

So you should follow the installation guide of Material UI Picker [here](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/getting-started/installation).

Try this:

```js
import React from "react";
import {
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
  KeyboardDatePicker,
} from "@material-ui/pickers";
import MomentUtils from "@date-io/moment";

export default function MaterialUIPickers() {
  // The first commit of Material-UI
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = React.useState(new Date());

  const handleDateChange = (date) => {
    setSelectedDate(date);
  };

  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
      <KeyboardDatePicker
        value={selectedDate}
        onChange={(date) => handleDateChange(date)}
        format="DD/MMM/YYYY"
      />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Select with checkboxes and sub headers]

Comment: Yeap. I have followed the installation and everything works fine. However, it does not accept characters for the months when I type.